# Copy and rename image to folder on Win 8 app

Tags: c#, image, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, async-await

I have an image on my Win 8 metro app and I want to copy it to a folder previously set and rename it to the actual date and time.
The only thing I can't get to work is the image copying.

```
private async void CreateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string DateTimeNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmssddMMyyyy");
    StorageFolder docs = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
    StorageFolder MyFolder = await docs.CreateFolderAsync("MyFolder", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    StorageFile Img = await GetFileAsync(ImagePreview.Source.ToString()); // This is the part that I have no idea what I'm doing (nor how to)
    StorageFile copyFile = await Img.CopyAsync(MyFolder, DateTimeNow, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
}
```

This is the ImagePreview XAML code (source is set on a FileOpenPicker)

```
    <Image x:Name="ImagePreview" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is to save the original `StorageFile` from the `FileOpenPicker` call. Perhaps you can create a member variable in the page for this. You can then just use the member variable (rather than the `Img` variable) to do the copy.